# Easy way to get size of folder (ObjC/Cocoa)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, size, directory, nsfilemanager

Right now I'm using this code to get the size of a folder:

```
NSArray *contents;
NSEnumerator *enumerator;
NSString *path;
contents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsAtPath:folderPath];
enumerator = [contents objectEnumerator];
while (path = [enumerator nextObject]) {
    NSDictionary *fattrib = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileAttributesAtPath:[folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:path] traverseLink:YES];
    fileSize +=[fattrib fileSize];
}
        
[contents release];
[path release];
```

The problem is that its highly innacurate. It either adds a few megabytes or deducts a few megabytes from the actual size. For example I got the file size of an .app bundle and this method reported 16.2MB, whereas the actual thing is 15.8.

What's the best way to get the size of a folder?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone using this under Sandboxing? :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I needed to do this today myself, and I've found that the code in [this post on the Cocoa-dev list](http://web.archive.org/web/20080907020151/http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/message/cocoa/2005/5/20/136503) is super fast and matches what Finder says to the byte.  (don't forget to OR in the kFSCatInfoRsrcSizes flag so you get resource fork sizes, too!)

If you need more explanation on how to use it, just leave a comment and I'll edit this post. =)

Comment: Thanks, what's a good way to convert an NSString containing a path to an FSRef?

Thanks

Comment: Just answered your question. =)

Comment: @Dave, this link is broken, could you update it or place code to answer?

Comment: @Igor fixed w/ an archive.org link

Comment: Thanks for fast reply!

Comment: Do you think it's still up to date solution?

Comment: Fundamentally, probably. It's possible portions of the api have been superseded in the past 12 years though ;)

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for `fileSize` states it does not include the size of a resource fork. You may need to use the [Carbon File Manager API](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html) to reliably calculate directory sizes.

Comment: Ah yes, that's another possibility. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to second Dave DeLong's suggestion about the post on Cocoa-dev, but add a cautionary note to be sure to read all the posts in the thread.  There is one by Rosyna that's particularly worth noting.  In my case I followed that advice (changing max items per fetch to 40) and saw a speed jump as well as the end to a nasty crashing bug.

Comment: Might be better to add this as a comment to his answer so they stay related even as their positions on the page change.

Comment: I'm having problems with Dave DeLong's method. I use this code to convert my NSString into an FSRef:

FSRef f;
  OSStatus os_status = FSPathMakeRef((const UInt8 *)[filePath fileSystemRepresentation], &f, NULL);
  if (os_status == noErr) {
   NSLog(@"Success");
  }

And then I try to run the method:

[self fastFolderSizeAtFSRef:f];

However I get the error "incompatible type for argument 1 of 'fastFolderSize'"

Any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

hope this will help

```
- (unsigned long long) fastFolderSizeAtFSRef:(NSString *)theFilePath
{
unsigned long long totalSize = 0;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL  isdirectory;
NSError *error;

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:theFilePath])
{


    NSMutableArray * directoryContents = [[fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:theFilePath error:&error] mutableCopy];


    for (NSString *fileName in directoryContents)
    {
        if (([fileName rangeOfString:@".DS_Store"].location != NSNotFound) )
            continue;



            NSString *path = [theFilePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
            if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isdirectory] && isdirectory  )
            {

                    totalSize =  totalSize + [self fastFolderSizeAtFSRef:path];



            }
            else
            {
                unsigned long long fileSize = [[fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&error] fileSize];
                totalSize = totalSize + fileSize;
            }
    }
}
return totalSize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is typically how it is done. 2 possibilities:

1. Check your byte -> megabyte conversion routines. Also, do you want megabytes or mebibytes? (It probably depends on what you're comparing it to.)
2. Try passing NO for the `traverseLink` parameter. There might very well be a symlink in the bundle pointing to something else that the routine you're comparing it to won't account for. You'll either count something in the bundle twice, or you'll include something outside the bundle entirely (most likely the former).

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old topic. But for anyone out there looking for answers on how to do this,

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir];
        if (isDir) {
            NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
            NSTask *t = [[[NSTask alloc] init] autorelease];
            [t setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/du"];
            [t setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-k", @"-d", @"0", path, nil]];
            [t setStandardOutput:pipe];
            [t setStandardError:[NSPipe pipe]];

            [t launch];

            [t waitUntilExit];

            NSString *sizeString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[[pipe fileHandleForReading] availableData] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
            sizeString = [[sizeString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
            bytes = [sizeString longLongValue]*1024;
        }
        else {
            bytes = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil] fileSize];
        }
```

It will use terminal to determine a size for folders in bytes. And it will use Cocoa's built in NSFileManager to get the size of files. It's very fast, and gets the exact size that finder reports.

Comment: while this will certainly work, you have the performance hit of creating another process (which can be pretty expensive), or using `NSFileManager`, which doesn't include resource forks when calculating sizes.

Answer (score 1):

This code is as extension(category) to the NSFileManager class. It sums the sizes of all folder content.
 Note that error treatment could be enhanced.

```
 @interface NSFileManager(Util)

        - (NSNumber *)sizeForFolderAtPath:(NSString *) source error:(NSError **)error;

    @end

    @implementation NSFileManager(Util)

        - (NSNumber *)sizeForFolderAtPath:(NSString *) source error:(NSError **)error
        {
            NSArray * contents;
            unsigned long long size = 0;
            NSEnumerator * enumerator;
            NSString * path;
            BOOL isDirectory;

            // Determine Paths to Add 
            if ([self fileExistsAtPath:source isDirectory:&isDirectory] && isDirectory) 
            { 
                contents = [self subpathsAtPath:source]; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                contents = [NSArray array];
            }
            // Add Size Of All Paths 
            enumerator = [contents objectEnumerator]; 
            while (path = [enumerator nextObject]) 
            {
                NSDictionary * fattrs = [self attributesOfItemAtPath: [ source stringByAppendingPathComponent:path ] error:error];
                size += [[fattrs objectForKey:NSFileSize] unsignedLongLongValue]; 
            }
            // Return Total Size in Bytes 

            return [ NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:size];
        }

        @end
```